# npm script running for preinstall, but not for preupdate

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a script referenced in packages.json for a node app.

The script is run fine when I do

```
npm install
```

but not for

```
npm update
```

The excerpt from packages.json is

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "preinstall": "node scripts/install.js",
    "preupdate": "node scripts/install.js"
}
```

The whole file is at https://github.com/Pike/outreach/blob/master/package.json.

Comment: Will `npm` still perform an update if the version hasn't been bumped up? Have you tried this?

Comment: npm update does run a host of stuff when I enter it, so it's not a plain no-op. It just doesn't run my script in addition.

Answer (score 5):

As I understand it they've disabled the scripts for npm update (preupdate/postupdate) -- something about best practice...

It's a complete pain in the ass -- they want you to use node-gyp and .gyp files for building node modules -- it has a dependency on python! No thanks!

I'm still banging my head on the keyboard over this -- since we cant install python on our production servers.

**Update**
Python is available on most Linux Distros, not too much of a big deal